# Why do I have to use "this" to access in inner property of a function

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between

```
function person(first_name, last_name) {
    this.first = first_name
    this.last  = last_name
}
```

and this:

```
function person(first_name, last_name) {
    var first = first_name
    var last  = last_name
}
```

Why only the first one makes `person.first` & `person.last` accessible outside the function?

Comment: Because in the second version of the function, the variables are scoped with in the function and behave similar to the private declarations in C#/Java/PHP etc.

Comment: because `var` in a function will set a local variable

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: If you just call the function `person(...,...)` then it won't attach the properties to the function itself, `this` would refer to `window`. You have to provide more information about the way you call `person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword within a function is called the *invocation context*.

1) If you define your function as a member of an object (a *method*):

```
myObject.someMethod = function() { this.x = 2; };
```

then the invocation context, `this`, is the object to which the method is being added, `myObject`.  So after calling `myObject.someMethod();` above, `myObject.x` is then 2.  The member `x` is undefined until you call the method, unless you defined it before.

2) If you use your function as a constructor with the `new` keyword, then `this` refers to the new object that is being created:

```
function MyX() { this.x = 3; };
var myX = new MyX();
```

You'll then have property `myX.x` set to 3.

Note that I called my constructor `MyX()`, not `myX()`.  You should call yours `Person()`, not `person()`.  It's just a convention, but it is useful to indicate that a function is meant to be used as a constructor.

3) Finally, if you use `this` within a function that you call as neither a method nor a constructor, then `this` refers to the *global object* (`document` or, equivalently, `window`).  Note however that if you are using javascript in `strict` mode (which you should do), `this` is undefined in such a situation, which means that you basically cannot use `this` in a function that is not a method or a constructor.

---

Your specific question refers to case 2), the constructor.  `this.x = 3` in the constructor just sets property `x` of the newly created object.  After some object `myX` is created, you can then access and modify `x` externally as any other object property using `myX.x`.

Answer (score 2):

when you write constructor function ( using `new`) - you add properties using `this.XXX`

then you do  :

```
var p = new Person('s','d');
```

and then you have access to `p.first` etc.

in the second example : 
youre not creating any properties..

youre only creating private variables.

so you cant access them...

Answer (score 2):

By using this.something you're saying that THIS is an object and something is his property.

By using var, you're saying that it's just a variable and not a property.

More information about variable vs property:
http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Because of [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

A variable lifetime is between the curly braces of the function. The `this` keyword allows to access the function properties outside of it.

Definitely take a look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 1):

'var' keyword make a variable scoped. In the last example var first and var last create variable accessible only in the scope of the function. You can see this as a local variable in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

when in javascript you declare a variable as

```
    var variable
```

it only exists inside the method where you declared it. If you want a variable to be accessible for everyone (that is, global) it has to be declared without the 'var' part

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to use `this`. It'd also work fine if you've got a structure like this:

```
Person = function(first_name, last_name) {
    var first, last;
    create(first_name, last_name);    

    function create(first_name, last_name) {
        first = first_name
        last  = last_name
    }

    return {
        firstName: first,
        lastName: last
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not really comparable given that using `this` works with `new person()`. Setting global variables won't let you have more than one "instance".

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was basically talking about module patterns. Gonna edit it now to make it clearer...