# Stuck in javascript closure scope limbo til my brains turn to scrambled eggs

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, scope, closures

**EDIT** : I just found something that works on every page load except the first (hard) load. It's a 'weird tip to get it to work' because it does not use onload. E.g.

This works on loads 2...n:

```
case String:
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            //context.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
        img.src = detail;
        context.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

This does not work on any load 1...n:

```
case String:
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
        img.src = detail;
        //context.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

I am not very happy that I miss the most important load (the first one), but at least there is some progress.

Can someone guide me to explain what is going on here? I'm really baffled. I want image to load and draw to canvas every time. Is this an unrealistic expectation?

I'm using FF 7.0.1 on Ubuntu, my user agent is : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1

**EDIT** : Still fail after all approaches tried in comments. I will keep thinking about it. I think it has something to do with the canvas no longer being accessible (even though the variable resolves correctly and no error is thrown in JS Debugger under FF).

I am writing a js framework for rendering to canvas to provide an easy API to write GUI with less code and prettier code than using Canvas API. It's just a wrapper around canvas. But I am not a js expert even though I love js, now anyway.

The following code in the closure can execute and access the scope of the img variable, can raise an alert form that scope on image load, can change the img css style properties, but will not execute a drawImage on the canvas context in context variable.

Before the closure context.fillRect will work fine, but inside the closure it does not. I think there is something fundamental I have not learned yet, since I have coded similar onload with closure looking code before and everything just worked. Hopefully today is the day I learn something new.

```
RenderProvider.prototype.drawImage = function(srcElement,context,state,detail) {
    if(detail == undefined || detail == null) {
        alert("Image is not present. Ignoring.");
        return;
    }   
    switch(detail.constructor) { 
        case String:
                alert("Image is from String");
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = detail;//'t.jpg';//'Star-Field.gif';//http://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
                img.onload = function (e) { 
                    alert('Drawing ' + img + ' to ' + context);
                    alert('Context dim ' + context.canvas.width + ',' + context.canvas.height );
                    context.drawImage(img,20,20);
                    return true;
                };          
                img.src = detail;//'t.jpg';//'Star-Field.gif';//'http://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
                break;
```

Comment: Try swapping the `src` and the `onload` assignments. This sometimes works because of caching issues.

Comment: Are you missing two `} }` at the end of your code?

Comment: Thanks I just tried it and changed above. But still fail.

Comment: Oh I just omitted the rest of the switch stmt. Js debugger didnt report errors and an alert I had in the onload still called.

Comment: What does `detail` contain when it fails?

Comment: detail contains an image file name in the same directory as the html file with the script tag that this is from. I also tried detail as URL. Just to be sure I alerted detail.It does contain this string.

Comment: I don't understand why that closure is needed at all in this case. Maybe there's some omitted code elsewhere to explain it, but that's all inside a single function already.

Comment: You are right. I don't need a closure, just a function. I will remove it. I removed it. Still fail.

Comment: Also, note that when you pull that image from the google.com domain, using it on the canvas will taint it. It's not clear exactly what's failing or how you're detecting it not working.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code back to pulling from the . directory of the html file.

Comment: By the way, you're not supposed to edit your code once you wrote it in the question; the comments and answers will seem inconsistent to others who read this later.  You can however add at the end of your answer something like "__EDIT__: here is some new code I tried after your suggestions..."

Comment: Oh that is a good point. I will.

Comment: I got the same bug on my FF. I'm not sure why it only happens on the firs load.

Comment: @Cris I'm not sure what you are referring to, but if something does not happen on subsequent loads, it's probably because the image is already in the cache then.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why the OP bug occur tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the window.onload event as well as the image onload event, as Phil H is suggesting. Are you doing that? I tested your first sample up there but waited for window.onload and it works on the first load. The second one does not work. I am not sure why.

Comment: Thanks I was not waiting for window onload. It works! I'd upvote you but I dont have neough

Comment: It still does not work on the other example though...At all. It's mind boggling.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJBr6/1/) that works if you want to play with it.

```
var img = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 20, 20); 
}​
```

Note that I use `this` instead of `img` inside the callback function.  `img` works too, but it's more usual to use `this`.  Also, you can but the `img.src = ...` after the callback function definition and it still works.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to jsfiddle. I changed to this. I played with the fiddle, put it inside a function. It still works. I have not yet worked out the above one though.

Comment: If you want more details on what `this` means in a function, you can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584205/why-do-i-have-to-use-this-to-access-in-inner-property-of-a-function/9584909#9584909).

Comment: It would refer to the object/prototype on which the function is called? In the case of new, a blank slate. Otherwise for a global function, the window object, otherwise the object the function is defined on.

Comment: In this case it refers to the object on which the method is defined, which is `img`.

Comment: I loaded my whole file at the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this function being defined? If you are defining this function in code in script tags, then the canvas element (and context) won't exist when the code is parsed, and cannot be passed in.

Note also that the closure will not be executed until after the block enclosing it has been run.

Comment: Okay that sounds good, everything is in script tags. I know the closure will not happen until the switch block is jumped to. But I did not think about script tags and page load order. So what happens? The script tag gets parsed first, so the context may not be ready?